# SAAS solution to monitor/graph/alert based on 3rd party API

Tags: api, graphs, monitoring

Our cloud computing platform (Google Cloud Platform) provides a daily report (in CSV or JSON) of the costs incurred.

I would like to create graphs and alerts based on that data. I can code all this, but if there is a SAAS solution that could provide the graphing/alerting part, it would be much easier, even if I need to do some development to puch my CSV/JSON data to the service.

Is there any such solution ?

Answer (score 2):

We make such a monitoring/graphing/alerting SaaS solution here at [Datadog](http://www.datadoghq.com). Here's our [API documentation](http://docs.datadoghq.com/api/) so you can inject cost data from the csv/json you are gathering.

We also support [Google Compute Platform](http://www.datadoghq.com/integrations/#google_cloud_platform) out of the box so that you can keep an eye on instances' performance.